# How to auto subscribe customer in registration process?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

There is a code for checked newsletter subscription in Magento 2 registration page like below.

[image]

Even if I click on the checkbox and register the newsletter subscription is not working as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error in `var/log` folder?

Comment: Please check with Magento's default template. If it is working with the default theme, the problem is in your custom theme.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento customer account create post page the code looks like below:

```
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
        $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customer->getId());
    }
```

If you see the data is posted correctly then you should look for the custom extensions which might be modifying the behavior of the method.

**NOTE**: This will not instantly subscribe the customer, he has to verify his mail first, depending on how you set it up in the settings at **Store -> Configuration -> Customer -> Newsletter: Abonnement options -> Has to confirm.**

So if the above method does not instantly subscribe, then check your mails and settings.